# Covariance Matrix of Uniform Distribution Positive Definite

Tags: geometry, probability-theory

Suppose that $B$ is a Lebesgue measureable subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$. Let $U$ be the uniform distribution on $B$. Let $x \sim U$, $\mathbb{E}[x] = 0$. and let $M = \mathbb{E}[xx^T]$, be the covariance matrix. What conditions on $B$ guarantee that $M$ is strictly positive definite?

EDIT: Figured it out. Suppose that $M$ is not p.d., then there exists $u$ such that $u'E[xx']u = 0$, which by linearity of expectation means that $E[x'u^2] = 0$. Since $x'u^2$ is a non-negative random variable with zero expectation this means that $x'u = 0$ almost surely. But that means that $x$ lies in $u^{\perp}$ with probability one, which means that up to sets of measure zero $B$ is contained in a lower-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Hence a sufficient (but clearly not necessary) condition is that $B$ is full-rank, i.e. contains an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Comment: Also, on this website, askers are expected to show some effort and/or some context relating to the question. Just click the edit button to add these details.

Comment: I answered this in the description through my other account --- topic closed unless someone wants to give a tight characterization.

Comment: @Shalop the author explicitly assumed that $\Bbb E[x]=0$

Comment: Assuming that $x'\equiv x^T$, what do you understand under $u^2$? There are at least three operations that can be called "vector multiplication". Also, how do you pass from $u'\Bbb E[xx']u = 0$ to $\Bbb E[x'u^2] = 0$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Oops, thanks!